# Predict a discret value with sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Can anyone help to teach how to predict the response of x=12? what is the command or instruction to enter?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
#Data

x = np.array([6, 8, 10, 14, 18]).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array([7, 9, 13, 17, 18])

#Instantion of the model

model_linearReg=LinearRegression()
model_linearReg.fit(x,y)

#Precision of the model

precision=model_linearReg.score(x,y)
print(precision*100)

#prediction of the model

prediction=model_linearReg.predict(x)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Your data does not linearly fit.

Answer (score 3):

Inputs for [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) or any sklearn classifier almost always are 2D `numpy` arrays with the shape `N_targets x N_features`; since your regression task just has one variable (`N_targets = 1`) and one feature (`N_features = 1`) you just need to wrap `12` into a list (technically *array-like*) twice:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([6, 8, 10, 14, 18]).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array([7, 9, 13, 17, 18])

lr = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
print(lr.predict([[12]])) # [13.56896552]
# probably want to unwrap as well
print(lr.predict([[12]])[0]) # 13.56896551724138
```